# Successive calls to moment.utc() aren't sequential

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout.js, momentjs

**Using Knockout, We have the following code running in typescript:**

```
    class timeHelpers {    

    private static createTimeBasedObservable(updatePeriodInMillis: number) {
        const nowTime: KnockoutObservable<moment.Moment> = ko.observable<moment.Moment>();
        let interval: number;

        const computed = ko.pureComputed(() => nowTime());

        computed.subscribe(() => {
            nowTime(moment.utc());
            interval = setInterval(() => nowTime(moment.utc()), updatePeriodInMillis);


        }, this, "awake");

        computed.subscribe(() => {
            clearInterval(interval);
            interval = undefined;
        }, this, "asleep");

        return computed;
    }

    static readonly utcNowWithMinutePrecision = timeHelpers.createTimeBasedObservable(60 * 1000);
    static readonly utcNowWithSecondPrecision = timeHelpers.createTimeBasedObservable(1000);

export = timeHelpers;
}
```

**The problem is that consecutive calls to**

```
   ...
   const now = timeHelpers.utcNowWithSecondPrecision();
   now.add(moment.duration(this.serverTimeDifference())); 
   // this.serverTimeDifference() is some numerical value
   ...
```

**produce values that are not always sequential**

Look in this attached console printout:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The 'add' method mutates the original moment by adding the time to it.**
https://github.com/moment/momentjs.com/blob/master/docs/moment/03-manipulating/01-add.md

The issue was solved by calling 'add' on a **clone** value:

```
  now.clone().add(moment.duration(this.serverTimeDifference()));
```

Comment: Also: http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time